# How can I create a custom task form in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

is there an easy way to create a custom task form with asp.net/Visual Studio for Sharepoint 2010? I worked with WSS3 before, where you can easily add the form URL to the workflow.xml file but in Sharepoint 2010 it wants an URN in the elements.xml what really drives me crazy because I don't get it to work. Most of the tutorials about custom forms I found were about creating forms with InfoPath or Designer but I can't use both of these programs. Is there a way to create forms in SP 2010 with VS2010 similar to the way it works in WSS3?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck posting your question at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/. The stackexchange site dedicated to Sharepoint.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new here and I didn't know that there is an extra page just for Sharepoint.